# RecyclerView item width become wrap_content after migrating to view binding

Tags: android, android-xml, android-viewbinding

Recently I move to Android View Binding from ButterKnife. All my layout are working well, but after migrating to View Binding, there is a weird behavior, all RecyclerView item have the `layout_width` as `wrap_content` instead of `match_parent`.

[image]

When I look at layout inspector tool, I see that the card view have `wrap_content` value for it's width.

[image]

But, I didn't change the xml file, so the width is actually still `match_parent`.

[image]

Do I miss something?

Comment: are you using constraint layout?

Comment: Put that card View in FrameLayout and make it match parent

Comment: Are you sure you used the three-parameter `inflate()` overload, and passed the parent to it?

Comment: Ah yes, when I added parent, and false to `inflate()` method, it's actulaly worked. @MikeM.

Answer (score 6):

In your recycler onCreateViewHolder, instead of this

```
override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): ViewHolder {
    val binding = ItemBinding.inflate(LayoutInflater.from(parent.context))
    return ViewHolder(binding)
}
```

Use this

```
override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): ViewHolder {
    val binding = ItemBinding.inflate(LayoutInflater.from(parent.context), parent, false)
    return ViewHolder(binding)
}
```